# Playing a video in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, video, xcode5.1

I'm developing a mac app that requires to play tutorial videos in the app itself.
when a user presses a button on the app it should play the video
here's the code for xcode 4.3 (incompatible with xcode 5.1)

```
@synthesize movieView;
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"video name" ofType:@"mp4";
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoPath];
NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *attrib = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber  numberWithBool:YES],
                        QTMovieOpenForPlaybackAttribute,
                        videoURL, QTMovieURLAttribute,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                        QTMovieOpenAsyncRequiredAttribute, nil];
QTMovie *newMovie = [[QTMovie alloc] initWithAttributes: attrib error: &error];
[movieView setMovie:newMovie];
[movieView play:newMovie];

}
```

I'm using xcode 5.1 for osx 10.8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple started a transition from QuickTime APIs (including QTKit) to AVFoundation beginning with OS X 10.7. There is a [detailed technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2300/_index.html) about that transition.

The easiest way to play a video in a modern Mac app is via AVKit (available since 10.9).
To get a basic view that displays a video bundled with your app you have to:

1. Add AVKit & AVFoundation to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section of your project
2. Drag an `AVPlayerView` to a window in Interface Builder
3. Connect an Outlet to the player view in one of your controllers
4. Instantiate an `AVPlayer` that loads the video resource from your bundle

This is the code to load your asset:

```
NSURL* videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video name" withExtension:@"mp4"];
self.playerView.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
```

Comment: how to play video in autoplay if the window loads?

Answer (score 0):

Thomas answer in Swift 5

```
if let videoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video",
                                  withExtension: "mp4") {
  self.playerView.player = AVPlayer.init(url: videoURL)
  self.playerView.player?.play()
}
```